# Kusto KQL - Run multiple control commands at once

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I want to run multiple command statements one after the other.
For example, I create a table and then drop it :-

```
.create table MyLogs ( Level:string, Timestamp:datetime,Message:string);
.drop table MyLogs;
```

When I paste the above 2 lines in the Query tab and click on execute, I get a syntax error :

```

Syntax Error 

 A recognition error occurred. 
 Token: . 

 Line: 2, Position: 0

 clientRequestId: KustoWebV2;xxxxxxxxx
```

I have a .kql file that contains multiple control commands that must be executed one after the other - How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.execute database script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/execute-database-script)

```
.execute database script <|
.create table MyLogs (Level:string, Timestamp:datetime, Message:string)
.drop table MyLogs
```

| OperationId | CommandType | CommandText | Result | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a25a49a8-91b9-46c9-9ca9-adef76573642 | TableCreate | .create table MyLogs (Level:string, Timestamp:datetime, Message:string) | Completed |  |
| e016fe3a-b655-4788-8ada-2b1a085bbd7d | TableDrop | .drop table MyLogs; | Completed |  |